# From AttributeDict to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm using Wikipedia's Pageviews API to see pageviews of multiple Wikipedia pages. To do that, I create a dictionary where I store the name of the article as key and the result of the search as values (the result is an `AttributeDict`):

```
list = ['Paris', 'Rome']
for x in list:
    dct0[x] = pageviewapi.per_article('it.wikipedia', x, '20150101', '20210101',
                        access='all-access', agent='all-agents', granularity='monthly')
```

So that the result is

```
{'Paris': AttrDict({'items': [{'project': 'it.wikipedia', 'article': 'Paris', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 890},  (etc.)
```

I would like to create a dataframe for each dictionary, so that I would have:
**Paris dataframe**

```
timestamp, views
201507100, 890
201507101, 900
```

And the same for the Rome dataframe. But it seems like me accessing the AttributeDict given from the API is impossible. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`AttrDict` is a `dict` so can be used wherever a `dict` is used, see https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict

Specifically in your case this produces what you want, I believe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dct0['Paris']['items'])[['timestamp','views']]
```

it looks like this

```
    timestamp   views
0   2015070100  890
1   2015080100  879
2   2015090100  971
3   2015100100  1097
4   2015110100  2259
... ... ...
61  2020080100  729
62  2020090100  665
63  2020100100  734
64  2020110100  1020
65  2020120100  918
66 rows × 2 columns
```

### Edit

to get these in a loop let's put them in a dictionary indexed by city name

```
city_list = ['Paris', 'Rome']
city_dfs = {}
for x in city_list :
    city_dict = pageviewapi.per_article('it.wikipedia', x, '20150101', '20210101',
                        access='all-access', agent='all-agents', granularity='monthly')
    city_df = pd.DataFrame(city_dict['items'])[['timestamp','views']]
    city_dfs [x] = city_df
```

Then you can access as such:

```
print(city_dfs['Paris'])
```

Comment: thank you, I was wondering how to do it dynamically. Like in the for loop, how do I distinguish the name of each dataframe for each city? I don't want to do it manually as the list is actually long

Comment: what do you want the oiutput to be? a list of dataframes? a dictionary of dataframes?

Comment: each dataframe is a city... idk the best way to access them then

Comment: pls see my edit